# Is there a way in Androguard to determine whether a method is actually callable?

Tags: android, code-analysis, static-analysis, static-code-analysis, androguard

I want to do a static analysis of an Android app with [Androguard](https://github.com/androguard/androguard). Particularly, I am interested to identify whether a particular library method is called. However, as the method call could be in a part of the code that is never reached, would the static analysis with Androguard account for that? If not, is there a different tool that I can use? (On a side note, as I need to do a large-scale analysis of many apps, the tool should be automatable, which I understand is the case for Androguard.)

Comment: Determining whether a particular line of code is executed is Undecidable, so any implementation of this wouldn't be perfect. I'm not familiar with Androguard, though, so I don't know if it takes care of this in obviously unreachable code blocks.

Comment: Your question is Androguard specific. Dead code can be detected at compile time and this is what even your IDE would do, not to mention tools like ProGuard

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) and create your custom [CQLinq](http://www.jarchitect.com/cqlinq) queries to query the codebase and check if a method is callable or not, many other possibilities are provided by CQLinq to create advanced queries.